# Issue with symfony 2.8

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, instanceof

Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Rocket\BackendBundle\Entity\PropertyRequest::setAgent() must be an instance of Rocket\UserBundle\Entity\Agent, instance of Rocket\UserBundle\Entity\Broker given,

```
    public function askQuestionPropertyRequest(Agent $agent,User $lead, $text,$type,$mls,$lsviewid)
{

    $this->propertyRequest->setAgent($agent);
    $this->propertyRequest->setLead($lead);

   // $this->propertyRequest->setBroker($broker);
   // $propertyRequest->setLender($lender);
    $this->propertyRequest->setSubject("Property Request From {$lead->getFirstName()} {$lead->getLastName()}");
    $this->propertyRequest->setMessage("Message: {$text}");
    $this->propertyRequest->setType($type);
    $this->propertyRequest->setCodemls($mls);
    $this->propertyRequest->setLsviewid($lsviewid);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most obvious anwser - wrong namespace used ?